# empty() only for ids greater than current id

Tags: jquery

I have 4 related selects for categories and 3 levels of subcategory

```
<select size="10" class="selcat" id="sel_0" name="sel_0">...</select> <!-- category --->

<select size="10" class="selcat" id="sel_1" name="sel_1">...</select> <!-- subcategory --->

<select size="10" class="selcat" id="sel_2" name="sel_2">...</select> <!-- subsubcategory --->

<select size="10" class="selcat" id="sel_3" name="sel_3">...</select> <!-- subsubsubcategory --->
```

I have jQuery/Ajax populating the subcategory selects onchange.

Everything works, except that onChange of any of the four selects, I want to initially empty any other selects which are lower than the changed one. So, for example, if a category is selected, I want the three subcategory selects to empty before repopulating based on the new selection. And if a subsubcategory is selected, I need subsubsubcategory to empty before repopulating.

The following script empties everything except categories

```
$(".selcat").not("#sel_0").empty();
```

How could I adjust that to empty any id number greater than what was currently selected. Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("select").change(function() {
    $(this).nextAll("select").empty(); 
});
```

You can be more specific with classes to.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wr27n/)